# Python alternative for header file containing min/max values of datatypes (and checking limits)

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, min

Greeting, my fellow home office refugees!

I'm implementing a python script which should verify if the specified min/max value are between the parameter's/signal's datatype boundaries. The input is a spreadsheet/table with the [minValue, maxValue, datatype] format, e.g. [0, 255, 'uint8']

Since we are talking about a C environment, I need to check for uint8, uint16, int32 and float32 limits. I stumbled upon a limits.h file, which has all the values explicitly defined, but I can't wrap my head around implementing it in my Python 3.6.8 script. My main target would be to keep it clean and simple, without redundant information, functions, hard-coding.

## limits.h

```
#define INT8MAX 127
#define INT8MIN (-INT8MAX -1)
#define INT16MAX 32767
#define INT16MIN (-INT16MAX -1)
#define INT32MAX 2147483647L
#define INT32MIN (-INT32MAX -1L)

#define UINT8MAX 255
#define UINT8MIN 0
#define UINT16MAX 65535
#define UINT16MIN 0
#define UINT32MAX 4294967295L
#define UINT32MIN 0

#define FLOAT32MAX 3.40282347E+38F
#define FLOAT32MIN -3.40282347E+38F
#define FLOAT64MAX 1.7976931348623157E+308
#define FLOAT64MIN -1.7976931348623157E+308
```

What would be an optimal solution to this problem? The best I could find is to create a dictionary and pair its keys with callable functions - but this means I should implement the check for every datatype separately. (or just create a dictionary with all the values and keys like *uint8_min*, *uint8_max*, etc)

## limits.py

```
def is_uint8(_min, _max, _dt):
    if _max > 255:
        print("[ERROR] Max value of parameter is incorrect!")
        return 1
    elif _min < 0:
        print("[ERROR] Min value of parameter is incorrect!")
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

_check = {
    'uint8': is_uint8,
    'uint16': is_uint16,
    'uint32': is_uint32,
    'int8': is_int8,
    .
    .
    .
    'float32': is_float32
}

def checkLimits4DataType(_min, _max, _dt):
    [_dtName, _dtSize] = re.split(r"(\d+)", _dt)
    print(_check[_dtName](_min, _max, _dtSize))
```

I would prefer a header-like structure for limits.py, with all the min/max values defined at the top, having as few check_datatype_limits methods as possible - ensuring maximum flexibility regarding its usage. Maybe define some classes which have an own method for checking the limits?

Thank you for your help in advance!

P.S. I read about the ctypes library, but it doesn't contain every value/datatype that I need to check, plus it doesn't check for overflows.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is to store min/max in mapping and have just one implementation of `check` function.

```
TypeRanges = {
    "uint8": (0, 255),
    "int8": (-128, 127),
    .
    .
    .
    "float32": (-3.40282347E+38, 3.40282347E+38)
}

def check_limits(mn, mx, type_name):
    type_min, type_max = TypeRanges[type_name]

    if mx > type_max:
        return 1
    elif mn < type_min:
        return -1
    return 0
```

And usage:

```
check_limits(-30, 190, "int8")  # Returns 1
check_limits(-30, 190, "uint8")  # Returns -1
check_limits(-30, 90, "int8")  # Returns 0
```

The only things you need to hard-code are minimum and maximum value for each type, but the code that checks limits is common.